# Chern class of reflexive extension of sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, pushforward

I have the following question. Let $U\subset X$ be an open subset of $X$ such that the complement $X\setminus U$ has codimension $\ge2$ in $X$. Suppose $L$ is a line bundle on $U$ such that $c_1(L)^2=0$. Now let $j:U\to X$ be the inclusion map and let $L'=j_*L$ be the extension of $L$ as a reflexive sheaf over $X$. Is it true that $c_1(L')^2=0$?

Any suggestions/comments are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $c_1(L)^2$? Note that $U$ is not proper in general. Also, what are your assumptions about $X$?

Comment: I mean the cup product of the cohomology class $c_1(L)$ with itself. I assume that $X$ is projective and the canonical sheaf $K_X$ is ample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. For instance, let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be a smooth quintic surface, let $Z \subset X$ be the intersection of $X$ with a general line (so, this is a finite scheme of length 5), let $U = X \setminus Z$, and let $L$ be the restriction of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1)$. Then $c_1(L)^2 = 0$ but $c_1(L')^2 = 5$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the example!

Comment: If I assume $X$ to be projective with klt singularities, and $U$ the smooth locus of $X$,  is the answer still no?

Comment: @AaryamanPatel: How do you define $c_1(L)$ and $c_1(L)^2$ for a reflexive sheaf on a singular variety?